# Nginx and PHP-FPM Clean URLs

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, url

## Preface

I have spent 40 plus hours trying to create a Nginx configuration setup that holds up to my OCD. I have been told numerous times on IRC that I am too picky and clean urls are very challenging to write. I am college student and System Administration isn't even my job! Regardless, I am seeking a perfect setup. This kind of configuration may not be possible in this world, if so let me know. If you know the answer, but want to get paid, let me know. I am thinking of creating a Github repo and setting up Tip4commit or BountySource to pay those that submit pull requests.  I think it would be great to create an open source best Nginx practices repository with lots of documentation. As for my actual question, I am going to break up my request/question into 5 parts. Some will be easy to do, however each part has to be compatible with each other and form into one Nginx config. This is the difficult part of the request/question.

Related Question: Is this too much work? Should I be using octohost.io, flynn.io, or github.com/progrium/dokku ?

## Clean URLs

```
foo.com/index > foo.com 
foo.com/ > foo.com 
foo.com/folder/index > foo.com/folder/ 
foo.com/bar.html > foo.com/bar 
foo.com/bar.htm > foo.com/bar 
foo.com/bar.php > foo.com/bar
```

Other Rules:
* Order for file type: .PHP,.HTML
* 403 and 404 send to /404.html
* Never add ending slash
* If a file and a directory are named the same thing, look for an index file in the directory, if there isn't one then look for the file.

## PHP-FPM Support

Besides supporting .html files, the master config should support .php files.

## HTTPS and WWW redirect support

```
http://example.com > https://example.com
www.example.com > example.com
example.com > www.example.com
```

## Template for the various types of basic and safe rewrites

Example: Redirect requests for example.com/feed/ to feed.xml, but don't show the true url.

## Best Practices for modern web development

Incorporate https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs into the master config.

## Security

Prevent rouge PHP from being run: https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/

My HackerNews Post: news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7640692

Comment: Is changing your application an option? Having a request router within your application works much better than trying to implement a particular URL scheme via rewrite rules on your HTTP server. Here is one PHP router: http://toroweb.org/

Comment: This looks promising, can you give me an example of how I would use it? Also, I am concerned about performance. Surely pure html is faster than php routing html?

Comment: Application routing usually works by all requests getting rewritten to an entry script (ie. index.php) and that script invokes your router which parses the URL and figures out what function / controller to call to generate that page. I don't know much about toroweb specifically, but application level routing is a very common pattern and alternative to HTTP server rewrite rules. Pure HTML probably would be faster, but it doesn't sound like you have pure HTML because you're talking about PHP-FPM. Sounds like PHP has to to parse the files anyway (given that you're rewriting .html to .php files).

Comment: True. Ok then, how would I begin to set this up? The examples show are all API related. Can you get me started?